# How to execute in right way Case management workflow?

Tags: workflow, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Executing the *Case management workflow*, I got an error:

```
> X++ Exception: Work item could not be created. Insufficient rights for
> user Admin.
> 
> Stopped (error):
> SysWorkflowMessageQueueManager-run    SysWorkflowMessageQueueManager-executeTask      SysWorkflowQueue-resume     X++
> Exception: Work item could not be created. Insufficient rights for
> user Admin.  at SysWorkflowWorkItem-create
> SysWorkflowWorkItem-createWorkItems SysWorkflow-save
> SysWorkflowQueue-resume SysWorkflowMessageQueueManager-executeTask
> SysWorkflowMessageQueueManager-run
> 
> X++ Exception: The workflow system could not access the business
> document data. Report this issue to your system administrator.  at
> SysWorkflowDocument-assertAsUser SysWorkflowDocument-assert
> SysWorkflowDocument-assertPermission SysWorkflowWorkItem-create
> SysWorkflowWorkItem-createWorkItems SysWorkflow-save
> SysWorkflowQueue-resume
```

[image]

The error is related in 
`SysWorkflowDocument\assertAsUser` method

[image]

The `Common` `rec` variable at *line 64* is void. The variable is populated by query:

```
select * from CaseDetailBase
    join CaseDetail 
    outer join CaseAssociation
    join CaseCategoryHierarchyDetail
    where CaseDetailBase.RecId == CaseDetail.RecId 
    && CaseDetailBase.RecId == CaseAssociation.CaseRecId 
    && CaseDetailBase.CategoryRecId == CaseCategoryHierarchyDetail.RecId
    && CaseDetail.RecId == 'My_Current_Case_RecId';
```

Missing the record in CaseDetail (child table of CaseDetailbase).

I don't have any customization about this area.

Do you have any idea how can I run the Case management workflow? Of if are there any fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a Contoso standard system? If yes, then you should create an incident with Microsoft support. Also search in LCS issue search for `SysWorkflowDocument`. I get three hits and one ([KB4015470](https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Details/373982?kb=4015470)) looks very much like your issue. Also [edit] into your question what version auf AX 2012 you are using.